# errors with the php filter module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

When I purposefully throw a php error from within embedded php code in the **php filter module**, Drupal displays the message `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

We like to send users with unanticipated programmer errors to an error handling page so that they don't land on a dead error page without us getting notified, so I'm trying to find out how to intercept this in Drupal. I've tried searching within Drupal for where this error string gets outputted, with no luck.

How exactly does Drupal handle errors occurring within embedded php code, or more directly: how can I make it redirect to another page or catch the error in another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific error comes as a result of Drupal explicitly setting the PHP exception handler to a custom function (done in [`_drupal_bootstrap_configuration()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_configuration/7)).

The exception handler itself is [`_drupal_exception_handler()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_exception_handler/7), which invokes [`_drupal_log_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21errors.inc/function/_drupal_log_error/7), and that's where the error page is generated.

I've never tried it, but I reckon you'd get away with implementing [`hook_boot()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_boot/7) and using [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to provide your own implementation of the core Drupal functions to theme that error page differently.

It might seem a bit of a long way round but since `_drupal_error_log()` doesn't invoke any hooks (it probably happens too early on for that anyway) I can't see any other way to do it without editing the core files.

Comment: This helped me locate where the error message was being produced. Thanks.